# Is it O(1) retreival in hashmap?

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, dictionary, hashmap

I have a hashmap like this:

```
Map<TestBean,String>
```

where `TestBean` is a POJO class containing a few strings, say `str1`,`str2`. Two TestBean objects `obj1` and `obj2` are said to be equal if either

```
obj1.str1=obj2.str1 || obj1.str2==obj2.str1
```

So, when I retrieve a value from this map, is it still a O(1) retrieval?

Comment: This has been asked sooooo many times here.... :s

Comment: Flag it for closure then.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `O(1)` provided the hashcode implementation is reasonably uniform - in the worst case (if everything is hashed to the same bucket) it could be `O(N)`.

The trouble is that for this specific example you have precisely that worst possible case - given your either-or equality condition, I can't see a sensible way to implement the `hashCode` contract that equal objects must have equal hash codes other than to simply return the same code for every object.

In fact, I don't think you can even have a well-defined `equals()` in this case, as your condition is neither symmetric nor transitive

```
a1(str1 = "A", str2 = "B")
a2(str1 = "B", str2 = "C")
a3(str1 = "C", str2 = "D")
```

- not symmetric: `a1.equals(a2)` but `!a2.equals(a1)`
- not transitive: `a1.equals(a2)` and `a2.equals(a3)`, but `!a1.equals(a3)`.

Answer (score 1):

The amortized time complexity is `O(1)`. This **depends on the implementation of the `hashcode` function**. If you have a lot of collisions you will have increased complexity.

So basically it is `O(1)` in the optimal case and it will close `O(n)` as your `hashcode` produces more collisions. If your `hashcode` function returns the same number in all cases you reach `O(n)` since your map becomes a linked list.